# How to Turn a Mesh into Tiny Spheres in Blender?

Tags: mesh

How do I turn a mesh into tiny spheres in blender and make the spheres big enough so they intersect and there are no gaps between them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could  you give a bit more detail about what you want, maybe attach the blend file or even just a screenshot of it, or describe a time (if there is one) when this has been done before, otherwise your question can be very hard to answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an object and instantiate each vertex of its mesh or face with a child object then just scale the child object to the desired size.

[image]

If you want a more uniform coverage, use the remesh modifier or the quadriflow remesh function on the parent mesh:

[image]

Comment: where can i find this "quadriflow remesh"?

Answer (score 2):

The quadriflow remesh is in the object data > remesh

[image]